# Why doesn't Blender render from video editor according to settings?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

In Blender 2.79, rendering a video seems funky. I've set up the render details in default view as described below, to render a video to a certain location. I have the Compositing and Sequencing checkboxes selected. However, when I render, it just renders the non-video-edited scene.

When I go into the video editor, and use the main menu to Render > Animation, it ignores all the settings, and instead renders a bunch of stills to the default Blender location (C:\TMP).

How to render video?

Thank you! :)

Render details:

Frame Range shows differently between Default and Video Editing views. Should they be the same?

Post Processing:
Compositing YES
Sequencer YES

Output: My destination folder on D:\
The stills get rendered to C:\TMP\ instead.

Encoding: MPEG-4 container, H.264 video codec, AAC audio codec.

Want anything else?

Comment: please, show or describe all "render details in default view"...

Comment: ok, I edited the question to add details...

Comment: yes they should be the same... are you sure that you're not using two different scenes? each screen layout (like "default" or "video editing") can show different scenes even if you switch from one to the other, and thus different ranges and output settings...

Comment: Ah, that's it. I still get confused by which scene is active, as switching scenes doesn't update layout and switching layouts doesn't update scenes. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that I had a different scene open in the Video Editing view vs. the Default view. So, when I edited the render settings in the Default view, and then started the render from the Video Editing view, it was rendering a different scene with different settings.

Comment: This is a bit confusing having this problem and i really don't know what you mean since i have no separate scene according to the scene tab next to default layout tab and the render settings are linked for default and video editing render tabs so  it does not seem like they can be different.

Comment: Fixed it just deleted the strip and reposted it looks like it was only rendering what was in the video editor. my render would be black if it was NOT on the strip an would only show previous renders if it IS on the strip